# How can I find out if a class has `initialize`?

Tags: ruby

I have the following class

```
class Logger
  def initialize(message)
    @message = message
  end
  def log
    puts @message
  end
end
```

and when I access the instance methods that are defined on the class itself and not in the inheritance chain, I only get back `[:log]`:

```
Logger.instance_methods(false) # => [:log]
```

The result is the same when the initialize method is not defined in the class. I also checked if it is defined in the inheritance chain; it is not:

```
Logger.instance_methods.include?(:initialize) # => false
```

It can be accessed individually:

```
Logger.instance_method(:initialize) # => #<UnboundMethod: Logger#initialize>
```

for example to access its parameters:

```
Logger.instance_method(:initialize).parameters # => [[:req, :opts]]
```

How can I get all defined methods including `initialize`?

Comment: `instance_methods` method provides you public and protected instance methods and initialize is a private method  `Logger.private_instance_methods(false)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the `initialize` method is `private`. Therefore

```
Logger.private_instance_methods(false)
#=> [:initialize]

Logger.private_instance_methods(false) | Logger.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:initialize, :log]
```

Comment: He can ask for a boolean answer with: Logger.private_methods(false).include?(:initialize)

Comment: Thanks, that returns exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize it is private, as `Logger.instance_method(:initialize)` returned the Message object and I presumed private instance methods would be excluded there.

Answer (score 4):

[Declaring Visibility](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Declaring_Visibility)

> By default, all methods in Ruby classes are public - accessible by anyone. There are, nonetheless, ***only two exceptions for this rule***: the global methods defined under the Object class, and the initialize method for any class. *Both of them are implicitly private*.

You can just ask the same to your *class*, your class will tell you, if it has the method or not. look this [`private_method_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-private_method_defined-3F)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Foo
  def initialize
  end
end

Foo.private_method_defined?(:initialize) # => true
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the explanation of the initialize methods visibility!